# No manifest created in MediaPackage, working from the AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, manifest, endpoint, aws-mediastore, aws-mediapackage

Just getting started on AWS, beginning by using the AWS web interface to begin learning. Doing the training module creating a live feed using MediaLive and MediaPackage. In MediaPackage I've created a channel and then an endpoint (manifest name remains the default "index").  In the training module, the manifest is automatically created. As I do it, no manifest is created, nor does there appear to be any way to create a manifest. As I said, just getting started, but frustrated when documentation doesn't align with user experience. What silly thing am I doing or not doing?